# How can I use the option PlotStyle to start plotting with second color in standard color rotation?

Tags: plotting

I would like to plot several functions in one plot and start the standard color rotation `(ColorData[97, "ColorList"] // InputForm)` from the second color and go on from there. What is the syntax for doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PlotStyle->(ColorData[97][#]&/@Range[2,n+1])`

Comment: Looks good but trying it, it still starts with the color blue rather than earth. Minimal Example: Plot[{x,x^2}, {x, 0, 180},PlotStyle -> (ColorData[97][#] & /@ Range[2, n + 1])]

Comment: You need to set `n` to the number of functions you are plotting, in this case 2

Comment: That works, let's put that into the answer as a note.

Comment: You could just use `PlotStyle -> Rest[ColorData[97, "ColorList"]]` if I'm reading the question correctly

Comment: Or `RotateLeft[ColorData[97, "ColorList"]]` if you still want the first color, but you want it to come in last

Comment: Yeah do that! It's a shame something like `PlotStyle -> (ColorData[97][# + 1] &)` doesn't work

Comment: `PlotStyle -> Rest[ColorData[97, "ColorList"]]` also works just fine

Answer (score 1):

Just to be perverse, I suggest making the 1st function a constant that will be skipped in the plotting. This has the advantage that you don't need to know the default color list is no. 97.

```
Plot[Evaluate @ {0, Sequence @@ Table[Sin[k x], {k, 3}]}, {x, 0, 2. π},
  PlotStyle -> {None, Sequence @@ Table[Automatic, 3]}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: interesting solution