# Plot: Option MeshStyle: color rotation matching PlotStyle color rotation

Tags: plotting

This is a follow up question to

[plot: option plotstyle: start with second color in standard rotation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112574/plot-option-plotstyle-start-with-second-color-in-standard-rotation)

I want the mesh points to have the same color as in `PlotStyle` or the points to not appear at all. Simple example that reproduces the issue

```
Plot[{t, 2 t}, {t, 0, 180}, PlotPoints -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 0, Mesh -> All, 
MeshStyle -> Rest[ColorData[97, "ColorList"]],
PlotStyle -> Rest[ColorData[97, "ColorList"]]]
```

I feel this not a duplicate to this question

[Different MeshStyle for different functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39438/different-meshstyle-for-different-functions)

as the goal of that question is not to match mesh and plot style.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different MeshStyle for different functions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39438/different-meshstyle-for-different-functions)

Comment: Maybe it's not an exact duplicate but that answer is an answer to your question too.

Comment: The answer in the other thread is not very helpful and does not relate to this question very well. I do not want to plot them seperatly and then use Show. I feel that that would be more of a workaround.

Comment: Indeed, because you can't use `MeshStyle` to color each function separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As showed in linked question, it can;t be done withing one `Plot`.

```
Block[{t}, With[{opts = Sequence[PlotPoints -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 0, Mesh -> All]},
   Show @ MapThread[
    Plot[#, {t, 0, 180}, opts, MeshStyle -> #2, PlotStyle -> #2] &,
    {
     {t, 2 t},
     ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[2 ;; 3]]
     }
    ]
   ]
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there an easy explanation why this can not be done within Plot? I am thankful for this example, do not get me wrong, but I would prefer an easier solution.

Comment: @AskingQuestions - it seems that `MeshStyle` isn't designed to work like this.  You can give multiple styles, but they are applied to the different `MeshFunctions`.  If you look in the help you find an example where they use red mesh in the x direction and blue mesh in the y direction.  I'd say the most natural way to do what you are trying to do would be to make a `ListPlot`

Comment: @AskingQuestions I don't know :-/ This is how I would do this. Not pretty buy at the end it is not so much.

Comment: You can also remove `MeshStyle -> #2` and  use `MeshStyle->Automatic` in `opts` (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another method,

```
Plot[{t, 2 t}, {t, 0, 180}, PlotPoints -> 20, 
  PlotStyle -> Rest[ColorData[97, "ColorList"]], 
  MaxRecursion -> 0] /. Line[a_] :> {Point[a], Line[a]}
```

[image]

Here the points will intrinsically match whatever `PlotStyle` you apply.

If all you are trying to do is include evenly spaced points in the x-direction for your plot, use `ListLinePlot` with `PlotMarkers`

```
list1 = Table[{t, t}, {t, 0, 180, 10}];
list2 = Table[{t, 2 t}, {t, 0, 180, 10}];
ListLinePlot[{list1, list2},
 PlotMarkers -> First@Graphics`PlotMarkers[],
 PlotStyle -> Rest[ColorData[97, "ColorList"]]]
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't respect `Mesh` specification.

Comment: Which specifications are those?

Comment: @Kuba, but it works here for `Mesh->All`.  I'd think a `ListPlot` would be easier....

Comment: Maybe you could give the example with `ListPlot`

Comment: @JasonB yes it works for `Mesh->All` only, sorry for generalization. It may be your method is better for OP, depends what is a final goal.

Comment: I actually use JasonB method now, but for a more general solution it seems one has to fall back to your solution Kuba.

Comment: @AskingQuestions and JasonB yep, `ListLinePlot` is fine there. My solution will be better for functions which plots benefit more from adaptive sampling done by `Plot`.

Comment: Yeah, but in those cases you shouldn't use `Mesh->All` because it's ugly  :-)

Comment: If Mesh is other than All, can try this: Block[{pts}, 
 Plot[{t, 2 t}, {t, 0, 180}, PlotPoints -> 40, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
    Mesh -> 7, 
    PlotStyle -> 
     Rest[ColorData[97, "ColorList"]]] /. {Point[x_] :> (pts = x; 
      Nothing)} /. {Line[x_] :> {Line[x], 
     Point[Intersection[x, pts]]}}]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the option `EvaluationMonitor` to retrieve the mesh points from `Plot` and feed them to `ListPlot`:

```
myfuncs = {Sin,Cos};

data = Reap[Plot[y = #[t], {t, 0, 2}, PlotPoints -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 1, 
Mesh -> All, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{t, y}]];] & /@ myfuncs // #[[All, 2, 1]] &;

ListPlot[Sort /@ data, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Style["\[FilledCircle]", 12], 
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[2 ;; 3]]]
```

[image]

(Of course, this solution only makes sense if your interested in the "adaptative sampling" of `Plot` as already mentioned in the comments.)